# Alternative on "npm run eject"

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, command-prompt, npm-run

Will a ReactJS app project be ended when I simply close the CLI, while in first instance the Node.js Package Manager was running the developer server through the "npm start"-command in the CLI? Or will the ReactJS app project run in the background?

If the second question is true, how can I otherwise stop the ReactJS app project without having to worry that I have to run "npm run eject" in the CLI and never being able to run the ReactJS app project in the development stage? The following occurs when I do so (run "npm run eject" in the CLI) for the second time:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\1st assembled M-PC\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\1st assembled M-PC\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\1st assembled M-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-27T17_27_41_529Z-debug.log
```

Comment: First, be clear with your question and be specific on what you asking. If you need a break,  just take one. `npm run eject` is a one time operation, you can not do it agian and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is running simply press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to halt it. Closing the Command Prompt will achieve the same result. You will still be able to run it again with `npm run start` after this.

A note on ejecting – to successfully eject you need to run `npm run eject` from your project folder. However this operation is usually needed only if you are a power user and you aren't happy with the default configuration.